Omniverse assets displayed in blue color instead of their actual colors
I'm new to Omniverse and I'm facing an issue with how my assets are displayed in the viewport. Currently, they appear completely blue, as shown in the first screenshot below:
enter image description here
However, the actual colors of the assets should look like this, as shown in the second screenshot:
enter image description here
Can anyone suggest why the assets are showing up in blue and if there are any specific settings I need to adjust?
Thank you for your help!
enter image description here
this is the actual view it has to get in the Viewport
but it is not comming
